Mouse completely dies on Windows 11 PC 0-25 times a day - power toggle on USB port fixes it
I have a (up to date) Windows 11 PC and a Steelseries RIVAL 5 mouse. Nothing fancy, just what was available in the store when I needed a mouse. The mouse is connected through a USB hub (becomes relevant later), but the same issue happens when it is connected directly to the motherboard.
Lately the mouse seems to just die randomly. Not all the time, but some times it just happens a few moments apart, some times it is hours between issues. I have not been able to figure out what it takes to reliably reproduce it. Moving the mouse does nothing, clicking the buttons has no effect. When it dies, I can unplug it and then plug it back in, and it works. Since the USB hub I have it connected to also has a physical button to power toggle per port, I can click that twice to turn power off and on again, and the mouse is back.
There are some fancy RGB lights on the mouse that always vary between different neon-like colors. When the mouse is in dead mode, the colors are still there, but static. When I power toggle and the mouse comes back to life, the "movement" of the RGB lights is also back.
I have tried running USBDeview (Nirsoft) and I see no events/changes when the mouse dies. When I power toggle, it disappears/appears again. Same is the case with USB Device Tree Viewer (V4.2.2) - nothing changes when the mouse is dead, but when I power toggle, I can see a reaction in this app as well.
I have Wireshark and USBcap installed (I know a LOT more about networking than I do USB), but I have not yet been able to find a filter that allows me to see if any "events" occur when the mouse dies.
Is it possible to figure out why this happens, and fix it? Is it likely that this is actually the soft/firmware inside the mouse itself dying, and it needs a quick power cycle to come back to life? What debug possibilities does one have to see why a USB device suddenly becomes 100% non-responsive?
This happens across reboots. I try to keep everything up to date, including drivers etc.

Sounds like the processor on the mouse is dying or unreliable. The lights staying on suggest the processor handling their colour changing has hung. It could be a dry solder joint, or bad wiring.

That doesn't sound entirely unlikely. I would guess the best way to find out if that is the case is to replace it with a different mouse, then, and see if anything similar happens.

I bought a cheap mouse on Saturday, waited until the other one died, and replaced it. Two full days later I have not had a single mouse death. I think the conclusion gives itself. Email to Steelseries incoming. :)
